# How to get second level Json value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to iterate over the second level json values in a response.

This is a sample of the Json:

```
  {

  "Links": {},

 "Items": [

  {

  "WebId": "A0EUfSms148rEStZ8_fh",

  "Name": "AA to Slurry ",

  "Path": "klj",

  "Links": {

    "Source": ""

  },

  "Items": [

    {

      "Timestamp": "2016-08-21T05:14:27.0180053Z",

      "Value": 0.0154830571,

      "UnitsAbbreviation": "%",

      "Good": true,

      "Questionable": false,

      "Substituted": false

    },

    {

      "Timestamp": "2016-08-21T05:14:30Z",

      "Value": 0.0155982981,

      "UnitsAbbreviation": "%",

      "Good": true,

      "Questionable": false,

      "Substituted": false

    },

    {

      "Timestamp": "2016-08-21T05:14:30Z",

      "Value": 0.0155982981,

      "UnitsAbbreviation": "%",

      "Good": true,

      "Questionable": false,

      "Substituted": false

    },

    {

      "Timestamp": "2016-08-21T05:14:33.024002Z",

      "Value": 0.0155704552,

      "UnitsAbbreviation": "%",


  "Items": [

{

  "WebId": "A0EUfSms148rEStZ8_fh",

  "Name": “Slurry ",

  "Path": "klj",

  "Links": {

    "Source": ""

  },

  "Items": [

    {

      "Timestamp": "2016-08-21T05:14:27.0180053Z",

      "Value": 0.0154830571,

      "UnitsAbbreviation": "%",

      "Good": true,

      "Questionable": false,

      "Substituted": false

    },

    {

      "Timestamp": "2016-08-21T05:14:30Z",

      "Value": 0.0155982981,

      "UnitsAbbreviation": "%",

      "Good": true,

      "Questionable": false,

      "Substituted": false

    },

    {

      "Timestamp": "2016-08-21T05:14:30Z",

      "Value": 0.0155982981,

      "UnitsAbbreviation": "%",

      "Good": true,

      "Questionable": false,

      "Substituted": false

    },

    {

      "Timestamp": "2016-08-21T05:14:33.024002Z",

      "Value": 0.0155704552,

      "UnitsAbbreviation": "%",
```

This is the code I have so far that returns only the name:

```
  var feat = resp.Items,
        tableData = [];

    // Iterate over the JSON object
    for (var i = 0, len = feat.length; i < len; i++) {
        tableData.push({
            "name": feat[i].Name,
            "Timestamp": feat[i].Timestamp,
            "value": feat[i].Items.Value,

        });
    }
```

So in this example this example tabledata would ideally look like this:

```
name        | Timestamp | value
AA to Slurry  
AA to Slurry
AA to Slurry
AA to Slurry
AA to Slurry
AA to Slurry 
Slurry 
Slurry
Slurry
Slurry
Slurry
Slurry
```

With the corresponding timestamp and value from the second level "Items". Right now all I get is the name value how do I get the name then iterate over the second level items?

Comment: Do you have JSON, or do you have an object ?

Comment: @adeneo I have JSON.

Comment: @llerdal We need to know exactly you have got the value of `resp`. How did you get the JSON into a JS object and parse it? What adeneo is saying is you are probably using a object in JavaScript rather than JSON, which is a text format file that you would need to parse into JavaScript.

Comment: I am getting it though   $.getJSON("websiteJSONCall ", function(resp) {   @SpencerWieczorek

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem is that your sub Items array is being accessed directly. (`feat[i].Items.Value`) instead you should loop through 2nd array as well. I put together this code to get you started, it loops through the items in the json you have then loops through the items inside each item of the first array.

```
json.Items.forEach(function(item){
  item.Items.forEach(function(subItem){
    tableData.push({
      'name':item.Name,
      'timestamp':item.TimeStamp,
      'value':subItem.Value
    });
  });
});
```